# Below Android 12 having android.app.RemoteServiceException issue

Tags: android

**I have defined target SDK Version 30. How can I fix this issue?**

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2250)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: You need to give us more information. There must be more logs that are relevant. Also the title of this ticket is "below android 12" and in the text you say you get this error only on Android 12. Which is correct??

Comment: I have seen the same error message.  It does not come with any additional logging so it not helpful for debugging whatever issue is causing the exception.